# different PIC microcontroller (USB CDC) install different drivers or share the same CDC driver

Tags: usb, driver, microcontroller, pic, cdc

I have a programmed PIC microcontroller circuit, which is connected to computer via USB. Now, the computer can recognize this "unknown device" successfully in device manager when the circuit is inserted to USB port. Then, the computer will ask for the driver.

I tried the driver mchpcdc.inf that download from microchip website, but it said "the best software for your device is already installed". I do not see a driver installation step happens. There is still an yellow exclamation mark on the "unknown device" in device manager.

I GUESS I need to change the code of the driver to fit the specific microcontroller's configuration? Or they just share the same driver.

Comment: This is usually governed by the USB VID & PID pair.

Comment: so you means i just need to use their official driver without any more coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the PID and VID are same in firmware code as well as in the INF file. As long as these values are same, it can be used in multiple devices, but do not connect the devices with same PID and VID at a time to the host.